# MFC conversion error

Tags: mfc

I got some errors in my MFC DOC/VIEW app with conversion LPCTSTR parameter(szNewChr), the error: error C2664: 'int ATL::CStringT::Find(wchar_t,int) throw() const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'wchar_t',
 and in atof method, I got error: error C2664: 'atof' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CString' to 'const char *'

This is my method:

```
void CmojaView::UpdateResultsWnd(LPCTSTR szNewChr)
{
// Ensure we are not trying to add a second decimal point!
if(szNewChr == "." && m_strCurrentEntry.Find(".") != -1)
    return;

// Update the private member variables
m_strCurrentEntry+=szNewChr;
CString strCurrentEntry(m_strCurrentEntry);
strCurrentEntry.Remove('*');
strCurrentEntry.Remove('/');
m_fResultsWndValue=atof(strCurrentEntry);
m_nClearBtnStatus=0;
```

}

These are data members defined in .h file:

```
CString m_strCurrentEntry;      
double m_fResultsWndValue;      
double m_fRunningTotal;         
char m_cLastOp;                 
int m_nClearBtnStatus;          
double m_fMemory;               
UINT m_nLastKey;
```

I would like to notice that it worked perfectly as dialog-based app...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18471079/1889329). It addresses the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a problem related to multiple-byte and unicode. Switch you project to 'Use Multiple-Byte Character Set' mode from Properties->General->Character Set.

If you still want use Unicode mode, change all the constant string from "..." to _T("..."),  '*' to _T('*'). Change atof to _ttof.